# How to retrieve User Access Token After Creation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, passport.js

I can generate user access when I log in or  Register a User

I want to be able to use the token later in API

I have questions

1. Is it safe to store user access token in the database after creation
2. How do I retrieve access token after creation

I tried this

```
public function showprofile(Request $request)
{
    $user = new UserResource(User::find($request->id));
    $token = $user->token();
    dd($token);
   // return response ($user);
}
```

> It returned `null`, I have checked oauth access token table, the user id I am sending is present.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1) yes, this is no problem. In fact, if you're using Laravel Passport, it will be done automatically. Passport's default migrations will make sure it's stored in a safe way. You can optionally publish the migrations yourself to adjust them if needed:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-migrations
```

2) If you've added the `HasApiTokens` trait to your user model. You'll be able to access the token like this:

```
$user->token()
```

Or if you need all tokens `$user->tokens()`. More info can be found in the [passport documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#managing-personal-access-tokens).

#### Update

---

You're trying to access the token on the UserResource. This doesn't contain the token(). Try to access the token before creating the resource like this:

```
public function showprofile(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::find($request->id);
    $token = $user->token();

    $user = new UserResource($user);

    dd($token);
   // return response ($user);
}
```

Also, I'd recommend you to use [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-model-binding). This will make your controller much cleaner since you don't need to look up the model yourself, Laravel will do this automatically for you.

Comment: Can you check my updated question please

Comment: It's the same thing, it returned null

Comment: Are you sure you added the `HasApiTokens` trait to your user model? If so, what is returned if you use `$user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken`? It might be that the way you create the token isn't correct.

Comment: Yes, I did. It created a token

Comment: Okay, then iguess I'll need more information, Can you update your question with your current User model and your controller as it currently is? Also check if the token is really set in your database.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the same problem.